# How to change header on first page

Tags: fancyhdr

For a report, I want to use the header on the first page to display my group members. But I do NOT want this header to appear on the subsequent pages. I've used fancyhdr to create the header and successfully removed the horizontal line underneath it, but I don't manage to make the header disappear starting with page 2.

Here is some of my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\thispagestyle}[1]{}

\begin{document}

% header without line
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\rhead{Group: Group member 1, 2, 3, 4}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! A command \pagestyle{empty} in your second page's content will do the job. But please... Edit your post to have `fancyhdr` package loaded and to show at least two pages (use `lipsum` or `blindtext`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what you want if I've well understood:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titleps}
\newpagestyle{group}{%
\headrule
\sethead{}{Tweedledee and Tweedledum}{}%
\setfoot{}{\thepage}{}}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{group}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Also a very elegant solution! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

For a single page, just use tikzpagenodes.  (I wasn't sure if you wanted it centered, left or right justified.)

Don't forget to run it twice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{showframe}% debugging tool

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \node[anchor=base] at (current page header area.south) {Group: Group member 1, 2, 3, 4};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this actually solves my problem. I was hoping fancyhdr would suffice, but for my purposes it seems even smarter to take a command that isn't even intended to add headers on every page.